# Some trouble when upgrade Ubuntu to 11.04

Tags: ubuntu

I meet some trouble when I upgrade my Ubuntu from 10.10 to 11.04. And I installed it on Vmware. When I start the virtual machine, I will enter the grub command line. By the way, One of my friends has the same trouble.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: what do you mean exactly? you mean it doesn't boot and stops at grub selection screen?

Comment: I had a similar problem (grub2 didn't recognize my `/` partition) when migrating 9.04 -> 10.04, this helped me: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Comment: @John: grub does have a commmand line (the selection screen is a somewhat user-friendly interface to that); and unexpectedly seeing `grub>` is a dreadful experience (it drops to the command line if there's no meaningful config, or an error).

Comment: grub> exactly :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. This worked for me: http://aaron-kelley.net/blog/2011/04/grub-prompt-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-11-04/

Comment: I boot the system following the instructions given by https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Using CLI to Boot. Then I fix the problem with the help of the your given url:sudo grub-install /dev/sda